# In SSRS How to limit start-end time within 7 days

Tags: reporting-services

I have a Report, I hope that if you choose to end time more than 7 days of the start time is prompt error.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than give your users two date parameters have a single parameter to select the reporting period. You can use a SQL query to generate a list of weeks and then allow them to select which week they want to see data for. That way they can't ever select more than 7 days.

---

Otherwise you can short circuit the SQL by adding a `DATEDIFF()` between the two parameters. You could use an `IF` statement for this but you'll need to ensure that it returns the same columns and data types or I think SSRS will error out.

Otherwise just add the DATEDIFF() check in the WHERE clause so it will return no rows if the parameters are too far apart.

You'll also want to create a textbox on the report and have it conditionally visible if the parameters are too far apart. Something like big red text explaining to the user that they have selected a date range that is too large.

But, I think showing error messages should be avoided when you can just adjust the choices offered to the user so that they can't choose something that is invalid.

Comment: thanks for your advice. I have achieved this function in my SQL statement.